# Will I lose colours saving a 16-bit picture as 8-bit?

Tags: bitmap

Let's say that I have a 16-bit photo and want to edit it using Photoshop. 8-bit graphics can display 256 colours per channel and 16-bit graphics can display 65,536 colours per channel, a significant difference.

So does this mean that a 16-bit picture can display a colour that does not exist in a 8-bit picture?

1. What will happen if I edit a 16-bit photo, set some pixels as colours that don't exist for 8-bit graphics, save the photo as 16-bit, and then display such a photo using an 8-bit display?
2. What will happen if I edit a 16-bit photo, set some pixels as colours that don't exist for 8-bit graphics, and then save the photo in 8-bit graphics?

Will the colours from the 16-bit palette that don't exist in the 8-bit palette be replaced by some algorith with colours the from 8-bit palette? How does it work? How does an 8-bit picture still look fine when it's converted from a 16-bit picture?

Comment: Most likely your hardware at best is limitted to 10 bits

Answer (score 1):

*"So does this mean that 16-bit picture can display a colour that does not exist in 8-bit picture?"*
I would say "decribe" instead of display, but yes, in a given color space.

*1.*
You will see the nearest value available in the lower bit depth displayed.

*2.*
You will lose the additional color intensity resolution, so your 16 bit color will be converted to the nearest 8 bit color value.

*"Why 8-bit picture still looks fine converted from 16-bit picture?"*
Because ~16 million color (24 bit) is enough for "fine" image reproduction

Please note that this is a simplified answer, obviously this can be more complicated (e.g. various sampling and dithering methods).

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you convert image from 16bit to 8bit is that colours will be converted to their nearest 8bit equivalent.

If you are asking if you would be able to see the difference, then  I would say it would be highly unlikely. 8bit per channel colour has over 16 million colours, which is many more colours than the human eye can differentiate.

There can be issues with editing 8bit images sometimes, such as when applying further processing which might exacerbate banding in gradients, but generally merely converting an image from 16bit to 8bit is not going cause any visible issues (except perhaps in some extreme cases).

Also note that most digital cameras do not actually capture 16 bits of colour. Even professional cameras somedtimes record RAW files in 12 or 14 bits per channel.

To avoid any problems, what I would do is make sure to keep a copy of the 16bit image if any editing needs to be done.  Export an 8bit copy for outputting, if necessary.